# IE9でクロスサイトの$.ajax通信後Cookieがセットされない

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery + xdr.jsでIE9ブラウザで通信後のresponseに含まれているCookieが保存されません。

```
<script src="xdr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

でxdr.jsを有効にして、

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: url,
xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
})
 .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
 console.log("done success.");
})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
console.log("fail.");
})
.always(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
console.log("always success.");
});
```

で呼び出しています。サーバ側も

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://<ここにドメイン名>
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

と応答しております（curlコマンドラインで確認済み）

doneとalwaysが呼ばれていることは確認できていますので、通信は成功しているようですが、応答されたSet-CookieによりCookieに保存されません。ちなみに、このurlは他のサイトです（クロスドメイン）。

応答されるCookieのみを使用したいのですが何かオプションか何か足りないのでしょうか。
ChromeやFirefoxなどではうまくいきます。
ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[こち](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154850/cross-domain-cookies-in-ie-8-and-9-without-an-iframe)の解答より、IE8もIE9もAccess-Control-Allow-Credentialsを支持していません。Iframeを使わなければ、IE9でクロスサイトCookieの保存は多分無理だと思います。若し両方のドメインとも修正できれば、サーバー間の通信は。。。？